# Returning values that only exist in two arrays of objects in vanilla JS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, functional-programming, reduce

I have two arrays of objects that contain a set of similar items

```
arr1 = [ 
    {property1: 'foo', property2: 'bar', property3: 'baz'},
    {property1: 'moo', property2: 'bar', property3: 'maz'}
]

arr2 = [
    {property2: 'bar', property3: 'maz'},
    {property2: 'bar', property3: 'santa'}
]
```

I need to write a function that takes the two object arrays as parameters. This function needs to return property1 of every object that matches the rest of the keys in array two.

so, my function should take the two arrays above and return only 'moo'. I've been at this for hours and can not seem to problem solve it correctly.

*caveats*: I would like to understand the solution without resorting to libraries, *and* I would like to solve it using a functional approach, without vars or for loops. hopefully using reduce() map() & filter() instead.

Comment: No your function should return moo

Comment: Use `.filter()` to get just the objects from `arr1` that match, then use `.map()` to return `property1` from all those objects.

Comment: We're not here to do your homework for you. If you've been at it for hours, you must have something to show. Post what you tried, and then we'll help you fix it.

Comment: @kevinternet Thanks, fixed

Comment: @cozysama are `property1`, `property2`, `property3` known keys?

Comment: Interesting homework question....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've shortened `property1`, `property2`, and `property3` to `p1`, `p2`, and `p3` respectively.

You've given no indication that keys will vary amongst objects, so this solution *assumes*:

- `p1`,`p2`,and `p3` will always be present in `arr1` objects
- `p2` and `p3` will always be present in `arr2` objects.

```js
var arr1 = [
  {p1: 'foo', p2: 'bar', p3: 'baz'},
  {p1: 'moo', p2: 'bar', p3: 'maz'},
  {p1: 'zoo', p2: 'bar', p3: 'maz'} // added to show multiple outputs
];

var arr2 = [
  {p2: 'bar', p3: 'maz'},
  {p2: 'bar', p3: 'santa'}
];

const match = xs => ({p1, p2, p3}) =>
  xs.some(({p2:y, p3:z}) => p2 === y && p3 === z);

const prop = x => y => y[x];

var out = arr1.filter(match(arr2)).map(prop('p1'));

console.log(out);
```

Some will criticize that `filter`->`map` unnecessarily iterates through the array multiple times. You can combine the filtering and mapping in a single `reduce` but I think the readability suffers a little bit ...

```js
var arr1 = [
  {p1: 'foo', p2: 'bar', p3: 'baz'},
  {p1: 'moo', p2: 'bar', p3: 'maz'},
  {p1: 'zoo', p2: 'bar', p3: 'maz'} // added to show multiple outputs
];

var arr2 = [
  {p2: 'bar', p3: 'maz'},
  {p2: 'bar', p3: 'santa'}
];

const match = xs => ({p1, p2, p3}) =>
  xs.some(({p2:y, p3:z}) => p2 === y && p3 === z);

var out = arr1.reduce((acc, x) => {
  if (match (arr2) (x))
    return [...acc, x.p1]
  else
    return acc
}, []);

console.log(out);
```

Mix/match the solutions to your heart's content.

Comment: @LucasKot-Zaniewski *"But reduce will narrow it down to only one value"* that is correct, but in this case I'm reducing to a single *array*... of multiple values ^_^ – I've added another matching case to the input data to show you the result of multiple matches.

Answer (score 1):

A functional approach with filter() nesting a some() without for loop:

```
var arr1 = [
  {p1: 'foo', p2: 'bar', p3: 'baz'},
  {p1: 'moo', p2: 'bar', p3: 'maz'},
  {p1: 'zoo', p2: 'bar', p3: 'maz'} // added to show multiple outputs
];
var arr2 = [
  {p2: 'bar', p3: 'maz'},
  {p2: 'bar', p3: 'santa'}
];
var result = arr1.filter(x => arr2.some(y => y.p2 === x.p2 && y.p3 === x.p3)).map(x => x.p1);
console.log(result); // [ 'moo', 'zoo' ]
```

Comment: nice improvement from your previous answer ^_^

Comment: I've learnt by reading and understanding (at least I've tried) your code ^_^

Answer (score 0):

I might do as follows according to `arr1`;

```js
function check(a1,a2){
  return a1.map(o => a2.reduce((p,q) =>  Object.values(o).every(v => Object.values(Object.assign({},o,q)).includes(v)) || p,false));
}

var arr1 = [ 
    {property1: 'foo', property2: 'bar', property3: 'baz'},
    {property1: 'moo', property2: 'bar', property3: 'maz'}
],

    arr2 = [
    {property2: 'bar', property3: 'maz'},
    {property2: 'bar', property3: 'santa'}
];

result = check(arr1,arr2);
console.log(result);
```

Chrome v54 or FF v50 seems essential for `Object.values()` to function.